# error in using logi.hist.plot command

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to show a correlation between a continuous variable and a binary variable, where the former is GDP of a province and the latter is whether a politician in the area was promoted.

I've been trying a number of things, but just plotting it would not show a very nice picture (it will just display arrays of dots at 0 or 1). So I'm using `logi.hist.plot` to show the correlation. But I seem to keep getting the error message:

```
logi.hist.plot(final$gdp, final$promo, boxp=FALSE, type="hist", col="grey")
Error in if (from == to) rep.int(from, length.out) else as.vector(c(from,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

1. Can this be due to `NA` values? Is there a way to remove the `NA` values in the `logi.hist.plot` command?
2. What other ways can you recommend when showing a correlation between a binary variable and a continuous variable? Is there a way to fit a line between the two by using plot command?

Thank you and I really appreciate your replies!